# Python : IndexError: list index out of shape

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

This piece of code works well when I used my earlier set of data. However Now I have added a couple more columns to the input data set and I am getting indexing errors. I am not exactly sure on how to fix this. Any inputs ? . The following code is giving me error:

```
with open("master_aggregated_monthly.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    data_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    rolling_queue = []
    for row in data_reader:
        if row[0].lower() == "salesforceid":
            continue

        # most recent rows go in first
        rolling_queue.insert(0,row)
        if len(rolling_queue) > 12:
            rolling_queue.pop()

        id = row[0]
        date = row[2]
        if id in company_dictionary:
            account = company_dictionary[id]
            #See if we are at the final event
            #get the final event from the list
            # most recent date for data collection
            if date == "6/1/2016":
                new_event = event()
                new_event.date = "7/1/2016"
                new_event.type = "Current Period"
                account.events.append(new_event)
                my_event = account.events[0]
                for entry in rolling_queue:
                # don't do anything if the entry in the rolling queue is not from the same account
                    if entry[0] != id:
                        continue

                    nonzero_row = False
                    # loop through the entries in the rolling queue to find at most the last 12 months of data
                    for i in range(3, len(entry)):
                        try:
                            my_event.attributes[i-3] += float(entry[i])
                        except:
                            #handle all of the odd string things
                            temp = entry[i].split(' ')
                            if temp[0] == '':
                                temp = float(temp[1])
                            else:
                                temp = float(temp[0])
                            my_event.attributes[i-3] += temp
                        # discover if this row is nonzero
                        if entry[i] != 0 and entry[i] != '0':
                            nonzero_row = True
                    # don't include this rown in the average if it's a zero row
                    if nonzero_row:
                        #print "Month increment"
                        my_event.months += 1
```

This code is giving me the following error

```
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Testing/The Scripts, JIC Test/Q4_12month.py", line 116, in main
    my_event.attributes[i-3] += temp
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should breakpoint line 116 and see what my_event.attributes actually contains

Comment: You should take some time and properly format this post (your code in particular, given that it's python). Secondly, you need to pull out and highlight the specific line you're having a problem with (how do we know what line 116 references?), and preferably a minimal, verifiable, complete example. See [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) for more.

Comment: The length of increased data columns possibly reflects in increased length of whatever `event` variable contains. And, hence forth increased values of `i`. Subsequently, `i-3`. However, length of your `my_event.attributes` possibly remains the same. And, hence the `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an index based off of the length of `entry`, but using that index in `my_event.attributes`:

```
for i in range(3, len(entry)):
    ...
    except:
        ...
        my_event.attributes[i-3] += temp
        ...
    ...
```

This is probably the problem, but it's kind of tough to tell what your code is doing. Generally, you'll only want to use an index on whatever object the index was created with / whatever object the index is supposed to refer to (in this case `entry`).

Comment: Thanks @zaychee. Any recommendations of fixing this ?

Comment: How are `len(entry)` and `my_event.attributes` related?